# Undefined index: posts_start on one localhost machine, but not on another? with Laravel 4

Tags: jquery, session, laravel, laravel-4

I have been trying to set up a "load-more" functional widget, and I was successful earlier today on another localhost.  However, on another computer (same Mac OS, MAMP, etc...), I am getting the error for the session variable:  Undefined index: posts_start.

In the javascript, these are the relevant lines:

```
<?php $number_of_posts = 2; ?>;
//<?php $_SESSION['posts_start'] = $_SESSION['posts_start'] ? $_SESSION['posts_start'] : $number_of_posts; ?>;
<?php $_SESSION['posts_start'] = 2 ?>;

var start = <?php echo $_SESSION['posts_start']; ?>;
```

This is using Laravel 4, so I already have a session running for the current user (no need to use session_start()).  I am not sure why this isn't working on this machine, but it was working on another.  Any thoughts?  Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use laravel's session class by the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely use Laravel's `Session` library.
This lib can handle situations like this beautifly...

```
var start = <?=Session::get('posts_start', 2) ?>;

// or this, if you use Blade syntax
var start = {{ Session::get('posts_start', 2) }};
```

What does this call do? It tries to get `posts_start` from Session, and fallbacks to number `2`, if number is not set in Session.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php $number_of_posts = 2; ?>;
<?php $_SESSION['posts_start'] = isset($_SESSION['posts_start']) ? $_SESSION['posts_start'] : $number_of_posts; ?>;
<?php $_SESSION['posts_start'] = 2 ?>;
var start = <?php echo $_SESSION['posts_start']; ?>;
```